# How to logout from Saml2aws cli session or do force login

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, saml

I have installed
`saml2aws` & `awscli`, to connect with one of the OKTA system.

I have made few changes in the config and want to reload new, but struggling with how to logout from session

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I have achieved this using

`saml2aws login --force`

Found [here](https://github.com/Versent/saml2aws/issues/318)